# Exchange Web Services - cannot get additional properties when calling "FindPeople" method

Tags: web-services, soap, exchangewebservices, office365

I'm making raw `SOAP` requests to Office365 and trying to get a list of contacts for specified `AddressListId` I successfully get a list of contacts, but it does not include all additional information I need. Once I add some additional properties (e.g. PhoneNumber) to my request, the server returns `Invalid shape` error.

Here is my request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
               xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"
               xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
   <soap:Header>
    <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013" />
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body >
    <m:FindPeople>
      <m:PersonaShape>
        <t:BaseShape>IdOnly</t:BaseShape>
        <t:AdditionalProperties>
          <t:FieldURI FieldURI="persona:DisplayName"/>
          <t:FieldURI FieldURI="persona:PhoneNumber"/>
        </t:AdditionalProperties>
      </m:PersonaShape>
      <m:IndexedPageItemView BasePoint="Beginning" MaxEntriesReturned="100" Offset="0"/>
      <m:ParentFolderId>
        <t:AddressListId Id="###-####-####-####"/>
      </m:ParentFolderId>
    </m:FindPeople>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

How can I get all additional information for each persona?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using EWS Managed API, so you will have to search for the raw SOAP calls on MSDN, I can only direct your search a bit:

I had a similar problem, because the very same is applicable for `FindAppointments()`. Asking for `AppointmentSchema.RequiredAttendees` will raise the `Invalid Shape error`, and `AppointmentSchema.Organizer` won't contain the email address, only the name of the organizer, after using `FindAppointments()`.

The solution was to do TWO requests to Exchange Server.

```
var appointments = calendarFolder.FindAppointments(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
exchangeService.LoadPropertiesForItems(appointments, MyAdvancedProperties);
```

I *think* that the same "workaround" is possible with `FindPeople()`, as well as every other `Find%Itemtype%()` EWS may support, I am not sure, though.

EDIT: I just found http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/e83abfb1-37a8-48fe-9579-4e120fb77746/ews-managed-api-loadpropertiesforitems-returns-unexpected-end-of-xml-document?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment where it is stated that `LoadPropertiesForItems` does a call to raw soap `GetItem` with multiple ItemIDs.

Comment: I don't want to do two requests. We have a big organisation and it will take a lot of time to iterate through every persona. According to Microsoft documentation this call is supposed to work, but it doesn't, so I'm wondering what am I doing wrong

Comment: I don't know about you, just best-guessing, but I am not doing anything wrong - it is just plain impossible to get Organizer or RequiredAttendees from FindAppointments. But my guess is that similar constraints also hold for FindPeople. Btw., MS has forums where you can get better answers to such in-depth questions, when their official documentation seems faulty or incomplete.